# How to split the data captured by lsof by commas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

The `lsof`utility is capturing some data that I want to turn into a Pandas dataframe. However the data has this format:

```
COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Spotify     377 estebanvargas   43u  IPv4 0x9d9dad438c107359      0t0  TCP localhost:4381 (LISTEN)
Spotify     377 estebanvargas   70u  IPv4 0x9d9dad43945bc031      0t0  TCP *:57621 (LISTEN)
```

I have been trying to do something like (for every row):

```
row = data.loc[0]
row = row.replace(" ", ",")
```

without any luck.

Comment: try row = `res.replace(" +", ",")`. You can also directly split and save in your dataframe using the same RegEx

Comment: You can use `lsof -F` for machine-readable data. It can be understood by reading the `OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS` section of `man lsof`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an XY problem. You are trying to read your data into a Pandas DataFrame. You don't need to mess with commas.

This is "fixed-width" format. Use [pandas.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html).

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = io.StringIO('''COMMAND     PID          USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Spotify     377 estebanvargas   43u  IPv4 0x9d9dad438c107359      0t0  TCP localhost:4381 (LISTEN)
Spotify     377 estebanvargas   70u  IPv4 0x9d9dad43945bc031      0t0  TCP *:57621 (LISTEN)''')

data = pd.read_fwf(raw_data)

print(data)
#    COMMAND  PID           USER   FD  TYPE              DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE                     NAME
# 0  Spotify  377  estebanvargas  43u  IPv4  0x9d9dad438c107359      0t0  TCP  localhost:4381 (LISTEN)
# 1  Spotify  377  estebanvargas  70u  IPv4  0x9d9dad43945bc031      0t0  TCP         *:57621 (LISTEN)
```

EDIT: please see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52847189/2954547) for a way to generate more easily parseable output from `lsof`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the more human-readable `lsof` format for input into other programs. Instead, use `lsof -F[information needed here]`. `lsof -F?` will tell you what characters to use just after `-F` to get various pieces of information. It makes parsing the information much easier to program and much more precise.

Also, you should use `0` (as in `lsof -F0[information needed here]`) to avoid problems with newlines in filenames and so forth. This will have the output fields separated by NUL characters (`'\0'`) and the output records separated by newlines (`'\n'`) for easy splitting and looping.

[`man lsof` has more information on how it works in its `OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS` section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lsof.8.html#output%20for%20other%20programs).

Comment: This is better than my answer! For the curious, you can read this output into Pandas with `pd.read_csv(..., sep='\0')`.